# Add Views to specific point on a WebView

Tags: android, webview, imageview, overlay

I have an image of a map that I have placed inside a WebView to enable zoom and scrolling. This works fine.

I know the latitude/longitude of the top-left and bottom-right corners so I can calculate positions on the map.

The problem is that I want to place a series of clickable points on the map at specific positions. I have got some success with setting the view padding and then using `webview.addView(pointView)`. The problem with this is that the padded area is made clickable as well, sometimes overriding other points. Setting a layout margin does not seem to work at all (clickable view is placed at top-left corner).

Anyone know how to solve this?